# AWS dotnet Lambda Serverless CloudFormation

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I spent a good day trying to figure out how to build/deploy a Restful API using .net 6 and AWS.  The hardest part was trying to understand the serverless.template (Variables/ Etc)

I figured I'd post what I did to tie all of the pieces together and hopefully help someone else that is trying to do something similar.

I know there is a more simple solution using "AWS::Serverless::Api" (BUT - this does not seem to allow too much customization?)

Here is a copy of my serverless.template

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Transform": "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
"Description": "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",
"Parameters": {},
"Conditions": {},
"Resources": {
    "MySampleWebApi": {
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
        "Properties" : {
            "ApiKeySourceType" : "HEADER",
            "Description" : "My Sample Web api",
            "EndpointConfiguration" : {"Types" : ["REGIONAL"] },
            "Name" : "my-sample-webapi"
        }
    },
    "ApiResource": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
        "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {"Ref": "MySampleWebApi"},
            "ParentId": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["MySampleWebApi", "RootResourceId"]},
            "PathPart": "api"
        }
    },
    "UsersResource": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
        "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {"Ref": "MySampleWebApi"},
            "ParentId": { "Ref" : "ApiResource" },
            "PathPart": "users"
        }
    },
    "UsersBatchResource": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
        "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {"Ref": "MySampleWebApi"},
            "ParentId": { "Ref" : "UsersResource" },
            "PathPart": "batch"
        }
    },
    "UsersBatchUploadMeth": {
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
        "Properties" : {
            "RestApiId" : { "Ref" : "MySampleWebApi" },
            "ResourceId": { "Ref" : "UsersBatchResource" },
            "ApiKeyRequired" : true,
                    "AuthorizationType" : "NONE",           
                    "HttpMethod" : "POST",
                    "OperationName" : "Users Batch Upload",
            "Integration": {
                "Type" : "AWS_PROXY",
                        "IntegrationHttpMethod" : "POST",
                "Uri" : {"Fn::Join" : ["", ["arn:aws:apigateway:", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/", {"Fn::GetAtt": ["AspNetCoreFunction", "Arn"]}, "/invocations"]]}
            }
        }
    },
    "WebApiDevelopmentDeploy" : {
        "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
        "Properties" : {
            "Description" : "Deploy Development",
            "RestApiId" : { "Ref" : "MySampleWebApi" },
            "StageName" : "DEV"
        },
        "DependsOn" : ["UsersBatchUploadMeth"]
    },
    "AspNetCoreFunction": {
        "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "Handler": "SampleApp.LambdaApp.WebAPI::SampleApp.LambdaApp.WebAPI.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
            "Runtime": "dotnet6",
            "CodeUri": "",
            "MemorySize": 256,
            "Timeout": 30,
            "Role": null,
            "Environment": {
                "Variables" : {
                    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":"Development",
                    "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT":"Development"
                }
            },
            "VpcConfig": {
                "SecurityGroupIds": ["sg-#####"],
                "SubnetIds": ["sn-#####","sn-####"]
            },
            "Policies": [
                "AWSLambda_FullAccess"
            ],
            "Events": {
                "ApiEvent": {
                    "Type": "Api",
                    "Properties": {
                        "Auth" : { "ApiKeyRequired" : true },
                        "Path": "/api/users/batch",
                        "Method": "POST",
                        "RestApiId" : { "Ref" : "MySampleWebApi" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"Outputs": {
    "ApiURL": {
        "Description": "API endpoint URL for Prod environment",
        "Value": {
            "Fn::Sub": "https://${MySampleWebApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/dev"
        }
    }
}
```

}